# Should I have two headers for both a) all the forward declarations AND b) the public functions

Tags: c++, header, declaration

Lets say I have file_a.cpp file where function_a() will be used in file_b.cpp, and function_b(), which will be only used in file_a.cpp. So what I thought of was making file_a_public.h where I declare function_a(), so I can include that in file_b.cpp. And then having file_a_private.h where I forward declare all the functions of file_a.cpp, so I could include that in file_a.cpp. I know that I wouldn't need the file_a_private.h if I just defined the functions in just the right order, but that can be difficult or impossible.

Is having two header files how I should do it, or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you wouldn't need the `file_a_private.h` if you could just define the functions in the right order. But then you could just *declare* those functions in the right order in `file_a.cpp` (possibly inside an unnamed namespace) before defining these later on. No need to include the `file_a_private.h` then.

Comment: So I should use header files only for public stuff that will be used elsewhere, and actual "forward declarations" just at the top of the file?

Comment: I think this is a question of style/preference. Personally, I don't see a purpose in producing header files if those are not going to be included elsewhere.